# Further refine pandas DataFrameGroupBy objects

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a fairly large data set that splits naturally into groups (let's call these "small" groups), but the analysis needed to determine those groups does not scale well with the number of elements.  However, there is a fast way to split it into somewhat bigger groups, each of which contains just a few small groups.  Now, in principle, I could go through each of these bigger groups, and split them into the small groups — refining the groups into which I split the original data set.  Because of the scaling issue, this is vastly preferable in terms of time it takes to do the computation.

But the obvious way to do this in pandas leaves me with separate "small" GroupBy objects for each group in the "big" GroupBy object.  Is there a way to simply split the "big" groups directly?

---

Just for the sake of example, here's a simplified version of a similar problem.  I first separate the data into "big" groups based on the "A" value.  Then, I step through each of the big groups, and separate each of those based on the `lambda` function.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [a, b, c]
        for a in range(4)
        for b in range(4)
        for c in range(4)
    ],
    columns=["A", "B", "C"]
)

big_groups = df.groupby("A")

for a, big_group in big_groups:
    # Let's pretend this lambda function is really complicated and slow
    small_groups = big_group.groupby(lambda index: big_group["B"][index] > 1)
```

Again, I emphasize that *because of the scaling* it would not be a good idea to just do the small grouping all in one go.

Also note that, just in terms of iterating over the DataFrame, I can get the behavior I want with this:

```py
groups = (
    ((a, b_gt_1), small_group)
    for a, big_group in df.groupby("A")
    for b_gt_1, small_group in big_group.groupby(lambda index: big_group["B"][index] > 1)
)
```

But this generator doesn't have the nice features that a GroupBy object would have.  So the question is: can I collect those groups into a single GroupBy object?

Comment: Have you looked into `dask`? It could be beneficial in your case. I could provide more advice, but the problem statement is too broad right now.

Comment: Ah, yes, I meant the latter.

Comment: You question is really broad and the sample data doesn't really reflect what you are trying to say IMHO. That said, I would just do: `small_groups = some_func(df['B']); df.groupby(['A', small_groups])` and passing any parallelization to `sum_func`.

Comment: @QuangHoang But what I'm saying is that a call to `some_func(df['B'])` would be really slow.  Basically, I'm specifically asking to split it into groups by "A" *first*, and then apply my slow `some_func` to each group.  Again, I emphasize that the issue is the scaling with the number of elements passed to `some_func`.

Comment: That's what I meant by your question is too broad and I'm trying to say that your settings might be very specific. In general **I think** that scaling on one single function on one series is a lot easier than scaling the nested groupby.

Comment: It sounds like you and I mean different things when we say ["scaling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Weak_versus_strong_scaling).  I mean that applying `some_func` to all N elements might take N^4 seconds.  But if I divide N into 10 groups and apply it to each of those N/10 elements, it will only take 10*N^4/10^4 seconds, which is 1000 times faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that this is the most elegant method, but it's possible to first separate the data into all the various groups, then extract the indices present in each of those groups, and go back and tell `groupby` to just separate by those indices.  That is, the goal is to create a dictionary that maps an index of the original `df` to the name of the group it belongs in:

```py
mapping = {
    index: (a, b_gt_1)
    for a, big_group in df.groupby("A")
    for b_gt_1, small_group in big_group.groupby(
        lambda index: big_group["B"][index] > 1
    )
    for index in small_group.index
}

groups = df.groupby(mapping)
```

Here, I've just used the values of the grouping operations as the group names; if it matters to you, you can change those to anything you want (presumably as long as they're unique and hashable).